# XMLHttpRequest when testing web-hosted REST api with localhost REST api

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, rest, asp.net-web-api

I'm attempting to test my REST service (Web API .NET 4.0) in AngularJS. 
As many other answers have proposed.

I've set up CORS:

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Accept,Content-Type,X-Requested-With" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

It would seem as if GET requests work fine. I've also continiously used PostMan to test various REST verbs. However when I fire off a **http.post** request from a localhost JavaScript application I'm receiving a `XMLHttpRequest` error. Which would be fair enough, if I hadn't explicitly allowed Cors requests...

Here is me sending a POST request to PostMan: 
[image]

Here is my http.post-request in AngularJs:

```
$http.post("http://api.worksiteclouddev.com/RestfulAPI/api/vw_PeopleListSiteAccess_Update/Get/", JSON.stringify(vm.content))
            .then(function (response) {
                //success

                vm.person = {
                    "firstname": response.data.Firstname,
                    "surname": response.data.surname
                }; 
            },
            function (error) {
                //failure
                console.log("Something went wrong..." + error.status);
            })
            .finally(function () {
                vm.ptsnumber = "";
            });
```

And finally this is what FireFox tells me when I attempt to fire that off:

[image]
[image]

**EDIT:**
How an option verb gets handled on the server.

```
    [HttpOptions]
    public HttpResponseMessage Options()
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK };
    }
```

Comment: does your API support the `OPTIONS` request (looks like it doesn't)

Comment: @JaromandaX doesn't it? `value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"`

Comment: does your **API** support it ... sending back `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` doesn't magically make your API understand what to do with `OPTIONS` request :p

Comment: The CORS snippet is from the server, so those headers are on the server, not on the client side. 

The server also picks up options calls as it would any other verb with the small difference of simply returning a 200 OK message.

Comment: Trust me, I understand CORS - search for *webapi.net cors preflight* to learn how to handle OPTIONS requests - i.e. they need to send back appropriate CORS headers ... **Aborted** sounds like the OPTIONS request is ... well ... aborted